# Fitファイルの作成方法

Tags: kotlin, garmin

[概要]

自転車の走行ログをFitファイルに落とし込み、Stravaにアップロードする機能をもつ
Androidアプリの開発をしています。
Fitファイルを作成するにあたって、fitSDKを使用しているのですが、
このライブラリをうまく扱えず作業が難航している状況です。。

[詳細]
走行中に取得したログには、あらかじめfitSDKが対応していないデータがあります。
例えば、ケイデンスを記録するFileldはfitSDKであらかじめ用意されており、

```
record.cadence = hoge
encoder.write(record)
```

上記のようにして書き込むことができますが、
住所(文字列を使用する想定)はFieldを自分で作成する必要があります。

現在、この住所Fieldを自前でrecordに追加して書き込む作業でハマっています。

[コード]
以下が、現在実装中のkotlinコードです。

```
val startAddressFieldDescMesg = FieldDescriptionMesg()
        startAddressFieldDescMesg.developerDataIndex = 0.toShort()
        startAddressFieldDescMesg.fieldDefinitionNumber = 0.toShort()
        startAddressFieldDescMesg.fitBaseTypeId = Fit.BASE_TYPE_STRING.toShort()
        startAddressFieldDescMesg.setFieldName(0, "startAddress")
        encoder.write(startAddressFieldDescMesg)
        val startAddressField = DeveloperField(startAddressFieldDescMesg, developerIdMessage)
        record.addDeveloperField(startAddressField)
```

エラーメッセージは以下の通りで、Fieldがうまくrecordに追加できていない感じです。

```
com.garmin.fit.FitRuntimeException: Incompatible Protocol Features
```

[判明していること]
・StravaはfitSDKのバージョン1のみサポートしており、バージョン2を指定して上記の実装をした場合に正しくFitファイルが作成される。
つまり、バージョン1/2でDeveloperFieldの追加方法がことなると思われます。

・住所を追加していない場合はFitファイル作成とStavaへのアップロードが出来たので、
住所Fieldの追加部分が原因でエラーが発生していると考えられます。

Fitファイルに自前のFieldを追加する方法をご存知でしたら、是非ともご連絡ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 作成時の手順や「アップロードできない」時の具体的な症状 (エラーが表示される等)を質問に含めると回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: 回答にはなりえないのでコメントしますが、Fitファイルはmessage毎にfieldのNoやデータ型がすべて決まっていたような気がするので、独自のフィールドは追加できない気がします(できるのかもしれませんが…これらの定義に関してはSDK同梱の `Profile.xlsx` で確認できると思います)。また、なぜ住所情報を日本語で埋め込みたいのか、を質問に書いた方がよさそうな気がします。スタート地点の住所を記録したいだけなら、スタート地点の住所の緯度/経度のフィールドを追加する、という方法もありそうなので。

Comment: SDK16.00の時に利用していたので `Developer Field` の存在を知りませんでしたが、SDK同梱のドキュメントを読む限り、 `Table 4-3. Definition Message Contents ` で `Only if Developer Data Flag is set` と書かれていますので、Record Headerの `Message Type Specific` に1を設定する必要がありそうですが、質問のコードからはそのあたりの処理が見当たらないようです。SDKのドキュメントをもう少しご確認頂くか、もう少しコードの全体像が分かるように質問を編集して頂くのが良さそうです。

Comment: また、 `Developer Data` が追加されたのは、ドキュメントのRevisionを見る限り、FIT Protocol 1.9以降なので、これより前のProtocol versionのFITファイルにテータを追加する場合は、FITファイルのHeaderの `Protocol Version` を1.9以上にする必要がありそうです(つまり自分でFITファイルをマイグレーションする必要がある)
手元のFITファイルのProtocol Versionでは、`10` (Garmin Edge 510J)、`20` (Garmin Edge 520J)の値しか確認できなかったため、 `19` を指定すれば良いのかまではわかりませんでした(ファームウェアのバージョンによっても変わりそうですが)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！！Profile.xlsx確認してみますね。また、Message type SpecificやFitprotocolのバージョンについての知見をご提供いただき本当に有難うございます。

Comment: すみません。。StravaがFitの`Protocol Version 1` のみに対応しているという情報が誤りでした。。(ソースが数年前でした)。V2_0で現在の処理を行ったところ、無地にuploadすることが出来ました。お騒がせいたしました。

Answer (score 4):

FitファイルにDeveloperFieldwp追加してStravaにアップロードする方法が分かりました

以下、解決方法です

①FitのProtcolバージョン指定を2にする

```
encoder = FileEncoder(file, Fit.ProtocolVersion.V2_0)
```

②RecordにDeveloperFieldを追加

```
val startAddressFieldDescMesg = FieldDescriptionMesg()
        startAddressFieldDescMesg.developerDataIndex = 0.toShort()
        startAddressFieldDescMesg.fieldDefinitionNumber = 0.toShort()
        startAddressFieldDescMesg.fitBaseTypeId = Fit.BASE_TYPE_STRING.toShort()
        startAddressFieldDescMesg.setFieldName(0, "startAddress")
        encoder.write(startAddressFieldDescMesg)
        val startAddressField = DeveloperField(startAddressFieldDescMesg, developerIdMessage)
        record.addDeveloperField(startAddressField)
```

住所(start)がFitファイルに書き込まれていることが確認できるはずです
(FitSDK同梱のFitCSVツールを用いてcsvに変換してExcelでファイルを開けば確認できます)

Comment: 解決済みにする方法あとで調べるので少々お待ちを。。。。

Comment: 自分自身の回答を解決済みにするには、[投稿から48時間経過する必要があります](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)。 / 特に焦る必要はないので、時間を置いてから試してみてください。